# Adding subdocument through array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hello gurus out there.

I am trying to add subdocuments through a dynamic array. Following is something I want to achieve. Not able to understand how to get array create subdocuments instead of getting it to print JSON code written in double quotes. I understand why it is printing code but not able tell the program to convert the string into subdocuments.

Thank you for looking.

```
rec = {
    '_id' : 1,
    'class' : 'Python'
}

rec['students'] = "[{'name':'Jack','marks':90},{'name':'Jill', marks: 80}]"

db.class.insert(rec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to quote keys in your dictionary, key `marks` in second element of list refer to variable `marks` which is not defined.
Try this:

```
rec = {
    '_id' : 1,
    'class' : 'Python'
}

rec['students'] = [{'name': 'Jack', 'marks': 90}, {'name': 'Jill', 'marks': 80}]

db['class'].insert(rec)
```

Comment: It worked !!!!!! Thank you very much for quick help. How stupid of me for not thinking of removing double quotes. Again thank you. Have a good day ahead.